# How to keep elements inline in case when they wider than their parent div with css?

Tags: css

I have 2 or 3 or more elements inside div like this:

```html
<div style="overflow:hidden;">
  <a href="#" style="display:inline;"><img src="http://j-time.ru/wp-content/themes/bulteno-theme/images/no-banner-300x250.jpg" alt=""></a>
  <a href="#" style="display:inline;"><img src="http://j-time.ru/wp-content/themes/bulteno-theme/images/no-banner-300x250.jpg" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

Though i have applied "display:inline" style to the elements and there is also "overflow:hidden" applied to parent div, when the elements (together) have more width than the div, the are shown one under another.

Just change the result window size and you will see. So why "overflow:hidden;" does not work, haw can i make these elements always be in one line, with hidden part in case when div is smaller?

Comment: Add `display: flex` to the parent div

Comment: Anchor tags are display inline by default. Overflow hidden is to hide things that overflow, in your case, nothing is overflowing. By default if something cannot fix on 1 line, they will wrap to the next and that is what you see. This is an easy problem to solve if you can get your images working

Answer (score 0):

Add "white-space: nowrap" to the style of the outer div:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden; white-space: nowrap">
<a href="#" style="display:inline;"><img  src="http://j-time.ru/wp-content/themes/bulteno-theme/images/no-banner-300x250.jpg" alt="" ></a>
<a href="#" style="display:inline;"><img  src="http://j-time.ru/wp-content/themes/bulteno-theme/images/no-banner-300x250.jpg" alt="" ></a>
</div>
```